# Node.js Set socket ID

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, real-time

Starting from the official chat example of Node.js.
The user is prompted to emit his name to the server through 'register' (client.html):

```
            while (name == '') {
               name = prompt("What's your name?","");
            }                
            socket.emit('register', name );
```

The server receives the name. I want it to make the name as the identifier of the socket. So when I need to send a message to that user I send it to the socket having his name (Names are stored in a database for the info).
Changes will take place here (server.js):

```
  socket.on('register', function (name) {
      socket.set('nickname', name, function () {         
         // this kind of emit will send to all! :D
         io.sockets.emit('chat', {
            msg : "naay nag apil2! si " + name + '!', 
            msgr : "mr. server"
         });
      });
   });
```

I'm struggling making this works, because I can't go any farer if I can't identify the socket. So any help will be really appreciated.
**Update:** I understand that nickname is a parameter for the socket, so the question is more specifically: how to get the socket that has "Kyle" as a nickname to emit it a message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store your sockets in a structure like this:

```
var allSockets = {

  // A storage object to hold the sockets
  sockets: {},

  // Adds a socket to the storage object so it can be located by name
  addSocket: function(socket, name) {
    this.sockets[name] = socket;
  },

  // Removes a socket from the storage object based on its name
  removeSocket: function(name) {
    if (this.sockets[name] !== undefined) {
      this.sockets[name] = null;
      delete this.sockets[name];
    }
  },

  // Returns a socket from the storage object based on its name
  // Throws an exception if the name is not valid
  getSocketByName: function(name) {
    if (this.sockets[name] !== undefined) {
      return this.sockets[name];
    } else {
      throw new Error("A socket with the name '"+name+"' does not exist");
    }
  }

};
```

Comment: Thanks Dave, but would you make it simpler. I'm still new with Node.js.

Comment: That's about as simple as it gets - basically you have a global object in the scope of the module, that you use to store the sockets. So say you get a socket and it has the nickname `bob`, when it connects you store it by calling `allSockets.addSocket(socket, 'bob');` - then when you want to retrieve it you do `socket = allSockets.getSocketByName('bob');`, and when he disconnects you delete it with `allSockets.removeSocket('bob');`

Comment: Great. how to emit a message to this socket: `io.sockets.emit()`?

Comment: `socketBob = allSockets.getSocketByName('bob'); socketBob.emit( msg )` ?

Comment: @mario Yeh exactly like that, or simply `allSockets.getSocketByName('bob').emit(msg);`

Comment: Note that the code above emits an exception if a socket by the name `bob` doesn't exist - so you can do `try { allSockets.getSocketByName('bob').emit(msg); } catch (e) { /* handle error here */ console.log(e.message); }`